# Shower valve not attached to a stud, how do I fix this without opening up the walls?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower

Previous owners did a reno on the guest bathroom and made some interesting decisions. The shower valve is not attached to any kind of stud and is free floating. Turning the shower on/off is difficult and it moves a lot. We have copper, so it's not the worst, but kinda annoying.

[image]

Best idea I had was brackets/hangar straps glued to the back of the shower fiberglass to at least keep it pinned somewhere. Opening up the walls to install a cross stud is not ideal but doable.

Comment: Is there a wall/room behind that valve that would be nicer to work from?

Comment: There is a small hollow space, but I would need to knock out some drywall to get into it. It's not impossible or anything, just annoying. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Drywall is easier to fix up after than tiles or whatever is on your shower wall.  Usually it is best to do the job well, than trying something that might not last.

Comment: I'm curious what we're seeing here though...is that a hole in drywall?

Answer (score 2):

Cut some wood blocks to wedge behind the pipes and use expanding foam to hold it all in place.

Comment: I'd probably cut the drywall and install blocking - probably be quicker than screwing around with wood shims/blocks and spray foam.  That said foam and wood blocks can work.